# If an NumPy array is a vector, why is the addition of a single number possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

In math you cant add a single number to a Vector scalar+vector!=, only multiply scalar+vector=vector. As far as I learned arrays are one dimensional vector, shouldn't it be impossible to add a single number to it then?

```
> x = np.array([1,2,3])
> x+=1
x=[2,3,4]
```

Shouldn't this be impossible?

Comment: `np.array` is little different from vectors and scalars in mathematics!

Comment: Numpy has magical broadcasting; Here is a primer: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: magic of operator overloading for numpy array when it see the operator it will apply to all the elements

Comment: Short answer: Numpy operators don't follow all the rules normally used for operations in mathematics.

Comment: Effectively that `1` is expanded to `[1,1,1]` to match `x`.  While a numpy array can represent a mathematical vector,, it is not formally bound by those rules.